# Opengl texturing 2D tile map

Tags: c++, 2d, textures, tile

I am having a little problem loading and applying textures on a 2D tile map. I am drawing my map like this -

```
for (int x = 0; x < m_SceneManager->getWorld()->TILEX; x++)
{
    //loop through the height of the map
    for (int y = m_SceneManager->getWorld()->TILEY; y > -1; --y)
    {
        switch(m_SceneManager->getMap()->cMap[x][y])
        {
            case 0:
                m_SceneManager->createTurf("Grass01.png", y*tileY, x*tileX);
            break;
            case 1:
                m_SceneManager->createTurf("Rock01.png", y*tileY, x*tileX, 1);
            break;
            case 2:
                m_SceneManager->createTurf("Grass01.png", y*tileY, x*tileX, 1);
                m_SceneManager->createTurf("Tree01.png", y*tileY, x*tileX, 0, 64, 64);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I am reading my texture text file -

```
std::ifstream maptex;

maptex.open(texfile);

if(maptex.is_open())
{
    while(map.good())
    {
        maptex >> m_Tile;
        maptex >> m_Eq;
        maptex >> m_Type;
        maptex >> m_Filename;
    }
}

maptex.close();
```

Both are two separate functions. M_Tile is the cMap[][] number, m_Filename is the texture filename. I have to remove that switch and load from this text file.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: These are two separate functions. I want to read that file than load the texture from that tile, then again read from that file and load the texture for second tile etc. Mean combine them into one function.

Comment: @Cobra: I don't see how having two functions constitutes a problem.

Comment: It was just my thought. I only want to know how do I make it work? Do I have to create arrays for each veriables to save that data?